# Getting focus info of child element or component

Tags: javascript, angular, events, dom-events

I am having a component which may have several child components at same level like

```
<parent>
  <input />
  <child>
    <input />
  </child>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

Either of child or parent may have `input` elements.

I am trying to get is if any of input element gets focus then its parent should get a call (other than manual). And if child component gets this info of input getting focus should be able to propagate it to parent without using `EventEmitter`.

I can use event emitter but if nesting of child increases then it would not be a good way. 
Can we do it more simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`@ViewChild` in order to get reference to the Childs and access their data from the Parent.

`@Input` to pass data from the Parent to the Childs.

`@Output` in order to trigger events from the Childs to the Parent.

If you don't want to use @Output a workaround that you could use is RxJS `BehaviorSubject` ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular)). Basically you emit values from the child using that BehaviorSubject and then you subscribe to those changes from the Parent.